# Chaining three CATtansform3D in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

Is it possible to chaining three `CAtransform3D` (rotate, scale, translate) in Swift?

I'm using `CATransform3DConcat` 
but it's only chaining 2 transforms

If yes, how i can do it?
If no, is there any "cheats" to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your transforms are called `t1`, `t2` and `t3`. Then do this:

```
let t = CATransform3DConcat(t1, CATransform3DConcat(t2, t3))
```